# Attempted to read or write protected memory on windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

so this is my code:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="#404040" Content="{Binding TripListSelected, Mode=TwoWay}">
   <Button.Flyout>
      <ListPickerFlyout Placement="Full" ItemsSource="{Binding TripList}"  SelectedValue="{Binding TripListSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
   </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

The < ListPickerFloyout.../> line is underline saying "Attempted to read or write...", but i can run my code normalny, and then when I want to clear the list (list.cleare() in .cs) I have runtime error with the same message. Is there another way to cleare it or is it a error in my xaml code?
Thanks :D